# Is it possible to pass arithmetic operators as variable in MyBatis statements?

Tags: sql, mybatis

I want to pass arithmetic operators such as (+, -)  in MyBatis update statement as a parameter and use it Like
UPDATE Products
SET Price = Price + 1;

except that + operator should be a variable in my case

Comment: can you elaborate more on it. it is unclear what exactly you asking

Comment: A sample of what you are looking for would be helpful.

Comment: I want to pass arithmetic operators such as (+, -)  in MyBatis update statement as a parameter and use it Like
UPDATE Products
SET Price = Price + 1;

except that + operator should be a variable in my case

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use dynamic statements

Say your interface is

```
interface myproducts{
   updateProduct(@Param("opr") boolean  operation);
}
```

Your mybatis sqlstatement would look like below

```
<update id="updateProduct">
  <set>
            <if test="1 == opr">
                Price = Price + 1
            </if>
            <if test="0 == opr">
                Price = Price - 1
            </if>
        </set>
</update
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I already know this way. I was wondering if I could pass operator as parameter.

Comment: I won't be possible I guess, If it all bepossbile its vulnerable to sql injection